# How to get four Y axis / spines to draw correctly?

Tags: matplotlib

I can't get this to work as expected The spines/text is always misplaced:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot 
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

host = host_subplot(111, axes_class=AA.Axes)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.1, left=0.2, right=0.8, top=0.9)

par1 = host.twinx()
par2 = host.twinx()
par3 = host.twinx()
par3.axis["right"].set_visible(False)

new_fixed_axis = par2.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
par2.axis["right"] = new_fixed_axis(loc="right",axes=par2,offset=(60, 0))

host.set_xlabel("Y axis")
host.set_ylabel("X axis 1 on the left")
par1.set_ylabel("X axis 2 on the right")
par2.set_ylabel("X axis 3 on the right")
par3.set_ylabel("X axis 4 on the left")


new_fixed_axis = par3.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
par3.axis["left"] = new_fixed_axis(loc="left",axes=par3,offset=(-60, 0))


p1, = host.plot([1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4], label="1")
p2, = par1.plot([1,2,3,4],[2,2,2,2], label="2")
p3, = par2.plot([1,2,3,4],[3,3,2,1], label="3")
p4, = par3.plot([1,2,3,4],[1,1,2.5,3.5], label="4")

plt.show()
```

Stackoverflow demand that I write more as the post is mostly code, so here is more texts to satisfy it, while the text in the beginning says all.

Comment: To be honest, without executing your code I have no idea of what you expect, but I expect it to be obvious once the code has been executed. You could have described what you expect and what you got instead.

Comment: Is it `plt.tight_layout()` you're after? Or `plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.1, left=0.3, right=0.7, top=0.9)`? Writing *"I can't get this to work as expected"* is quite uninformative.

Comment: On execution you can see "X axis 1,4 on the left" and "X axis 3 on the right"  - axis #2 is nowhere to see . (sorry for not describing that better)

Comment: So, did you try plt.tigjt_layout?